# What is the term for God's chosen people who were inspired to write the Bible?

Tags: bible, terminology, authorship

God chose men to write different parts of the Bible. What were these men called?

Comment: They're normally just called the authors of the Bible. Or you could be thinking of "prophet" or "evangelist" (for the 4 Gospels)?

Comment: I call them Bible writers. I don't call them authors, though, because God is the author.

Comment: Yes    One author many writers.

Comment: @4castle Kris Is that the common view of JWs? It would not be in Protestantism, where the dual authorship of scripture is recognised.

Comment: 2 Tim 3:15 is the basis for Jehovah God as the author of the Bible. Moses, David, etc. conveyed that which Jehovah gave to them.

Comment: They are called prophets and apostles.

Answer (score -1):

Direct scribes or people who could document the conversation that was happening at the factual basis. Which is where truth is seen. The facts only were written. So the technical term would be Scribes

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.